# Remotely wiping emails in android

Tags: android, email, remote-access

I want to remotely wipe email only (not factory reset) with/ without Device Administration. Is it possible?

Note: The user may use any type of mail client.

Comment: I think that's your job. If you have a _specific problem_ then I (we) could help.

Comment: Using RecoverySystem API i am able to factory reset.But i need to know is it possible to wipe email remotely or not.

Comment: Are your asking to wipe all the mails from email client of your phone??

Comment: Yes ,Haresh.I want to do it programmatically for any email client.

Answer (score 0):

After reading [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html), and as my experiences, I think without a factory reset, you can't.

Unless the user is running under `root` account, you can find all other apps' data and wipe it. The hard part is *"any type of mail client"*. There will be some apps you don't know of. And maybe some apps store data internally (device's memory) or externally (SD card…).

In any case, without factory reset, Device Admin can't help you.

Comment: I haven't worked with Device Admin before, hope [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html#wipe) will help you.